# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException don't catch exception

Tags: c#, exception

In my application I don't want that the application always crash if there was thrown a unhandled exception. I did some research and found a few EventHandlers.

On this [Page](https://dzone.com/articles/order-chaos-handling-unhandled) is writtin:

> In a typical WPF application you should use `Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException` for exceptions generated on the UI thread and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` for all the other exceptions.

In my case I need the `Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException` handler (I think so).

I did following. First in the App.xaml.cs OnStartup(...)-Method I wrote:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += new DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(Application_DispatcherUnhandledException);
}
```

I few rows below I created the method:

```
private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    //TODO: StackTrace
    MessageBox.Show("An unhandled exception just occurred: " + e.Exception.Message + e.Exception.Data, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
}
```

Is that all I need?
In my MainView code-behind file I create a exception:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)()
{
    string asd = null;
    asd.Trim();
}
```

After executing my programm still crash with a System.NullReferenceException, because the string `asd` is null. What did I wrong.

Comment: What is the _error log_?

Comment: What is the code causing the crash? The error call stack? What do you expect to do it after it threw an exception?

Comment: constructor exceptions are often more difficult

Comment: @BugFinder I updated the question. I tried it. The exception is still crashing the programm.

Comment: How do you define "crashes"? This code, as shown, should work fine and just show dialog box with error.

Comment: The statements in your `Button_Click` method are `string asd = null;` and `asd.Trim();`. That has the same effect as writing the statement `null.Trim();` and hence a null reference exception.

Answer (score 1):

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException is an event and cannot avoid app crash...

The only way to avoid application crash is to wrap your Application.Run method in a Try-Catch block. You will find it usually in Main() function.

The problem is that this can give you only the chance to restart the UI, because in the catch block your are outside the main loop...

I think the solution is writing better code, catching exceptions when necessary (if possible)...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, how can I get notified if a exception where in the core thrown? The problem is, the Application_DispatcherUnhandledException is doing nothing. It is not even called, so I can't give a notification to the user that something was going wrong?

Comment: Like @cse wrote you can register to `YourApp.Dispatcher.UnhandledExceptionFilter` and set `RequestCatch` to `true`, also register to `DispatcherUnhandledException` and, inside it, setting `Handled` to `true` will avoid application crash.

Answer (score 1):

Following is an extract from [msdn.microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherunhandledexceptioneventargs(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The UnhandledException event occurs when code executing by way of the Dispatcher throws an exception which is not handled.
>   The UnhandledExceptionFilter event provides a means to not raise the UnhandledException event. The UnhandledExceptionFilter event is raised first, and If RequestCatch on the DispatcherUnhandledExceptionFilterEventArgs is set to false, the UnhandledException event will not be raised.

So I suggest to set `Handled` property of `DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs` class to `true`, i.e. `e.Handled = true`, in `Application_DispatcherUnhandledException()` method.

**Update:**
You can also use [`UnhandledExceptionFilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.unhandledexceptionfilter(v=vs.110).aspx). Following is an extract from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.unhandledexceptionfilter(v=vs.110).aspx) link:

> **Remarks**
>
> This event is raised during the filter stage for an exception that is raised during execution of a delegate by way of Invoke or BeginInvoke and is uncaught.
>
> The call stack is not unwound at this point (first-chance exception).
>   Event handlers for this event must be written with care to avoid creating secondary exceptions and to catch any that occur. It is recommended to avoid allocating memory or doing any resource intensive operations in the handler.
>
> The UnhandledExceptionFilter event provides a means to not raise the UnhandledException event. The UnhandledExceptionFilter event is raised first, and If RequestCatch on the DispatcherUnhandledExceptionFilterEventArgs is set to false, the UnhandledException event will not be raised.

Comment: But if you read the question - OP already does that.

Comment: @Evk Answer updated!!!

Comment: Still at least first part is irrelevant, since OP says "I'm doing X and it does not work", and you are saying "Then do X".